# Rails Carmen get Country name and State name from code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

I am using the Carmen gem to render a country select in Rails. The country is stored as Code in the database. How can I get the "Full name" back from this code?

gem 'carmen-rails', '~> 1.0.0.beta3'

```
<%= f.country_select :country, prompt: 'Please select a country' %>
```

I tried several options, none of them worked so far! For example:

```
Carmen::country_name(@profile.country)
```

Leading to error:

> undefined method `country_name' for Carmen:Module

Second try:

in profiles_controller:

```
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
@country = Carmen::Country.named( @profile.country )
```

In profiles index view:

```
<%= @country.official_name %>
```

This leads to error:

> undefined method `official_name' for nil:NilClass

Why is my application failing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the test spec for carmen on github:

https://github.com/jim/carmen/blob/master/spec/carmen/country_spec.rb

```
@country = Carmen::Country.coded(@profile.country)

<%= @country.name %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for country name

```
@country = Carmen::Country.coded(@profile.country)

<%= @country.name %>
```

And for State Name

```
@subregions = @country.subregions
@state = @subregions.coded(@profile.state_code)
<%= @state.name %>
```

Hope this answer is use full.